# No error but strange behavior in executing Hadoop File Sysem commands from groovy script

Tags: hadoop, groovy

I am executing following hadoop file system shell commands from a groovy script to move hive generated files to hdfs.

```
targetFolderPath="/data/app/2016/06/30/"
srcFile=["/apps/hive/warehouse/customer_input.db/customer/year=2016/month=06/day=30/000000_0.txt.bz2"....]
dst="/data/app/2016/06/30/customer_20160630_201707151297.txt.bz2"


make_dir = " hdfs dfs -mkdir -p ${targetFolderPath} ".execute()

copy_file = " hdfs dfs -cp ${srcFile} ${dst} ".execute()


println ( " created folder  ${targetFolderPath} and copied file  ${srcFile}  as ${dst} " )
```

this command is running in loop. I am not getting any error but starnge behaviour

1. The first loop is always correct
2. In second loop the folder is created but file is not copied.
3. In third loop neither folder is created nor file is copied.
4. In subsequent loops no folder or file is created,
5. Sometime the copies file has .__copying extension

What could be wrong with calling this command from groovy? Is groovy not suitable to execute command strings on hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to wait for the processes to finish

Add `.waitForProcessOutput()` after all your `.execute()` calls